# Why in my theme I can't see all the statics content under the posts?

Tags: php, theme-development, loop, themes

I am pretty new in PHP and I have the following problem, I am developing this WordPress problem: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

As you can see it is shown the unique post present on my blog (the one named Hello Wordl) but under it the rest of my theme is not shown.

This is the code of the page and how you can see under the shown post there are many other static information that have to be shown:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Contenuti (griglia) -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Lead presentazione -->
    <section id="presentazione">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="text-center"><small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</small></h1>
                <p class="lead text-center">
                    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et...
                </p>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </section><!-- /section presentazione -->
    <!-- Progetti in evidenza -->
    <section id="lancio-progetti">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="box-progetto">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum sit dolor</h3>
                    <p class="text-center"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/pencil-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Acquista il pacchetto</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="box-progetto">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum sit dolor</h3>
                    <p class="text-center"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/pencil-2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Acquista il pacchetto</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="box-progetto">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum sit dolor</h3>
                    <p class="text-center"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/pencil-3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Acquista il pacchetto</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </section><!-- /section lancio progetti-->

    <!-- SEZIONE IN CUI VENGONO VISUALIZZATI I POST DEL BLOG: -->
    <section id="blog-posts">

        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>

        <header class="header-sezione">
            <h2>Ultimi Articoli</h2>
        </header>
        <article>
            <header>
                <time datetime="2010-11-10" pubdate>
                    10/11/2010
                </time>
                <h3>FIRST POST TITLE</h3>
            </header>
            <p>
                POSTS CONTENT
            </p>

            <footer class= "posts_footer">
                <address>
                    <a href="mailto:nonesiste@non.st">MY NAME</a>
                </address>
            </footer>
        </article>

    </section>

    <section id="ultimi-lavori">
        <header class="header-sezione">
            <h2>Ultimi lavori</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="box-lavoro-evidenza">
                    <h3>Il nuovo sito di HTML.it</h3>
                    <p>
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at <a href="#">eget metus id elit mi</a> egetine. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus etiam sem...
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus, <a href="#">tellus ac cursus</a> comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                    </p>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.
                        </p>
                        <small>Marco Rossi <cite title="Source Title">Direttore Marketing</cite></small>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-7 -->
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="box-lavoro-evidenza">
                    <img src="assets/img/work-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-5 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <div class="box-progetto">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Lorem.com</h4>
                    <a href="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-1.jpg" title="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com" class="fancybox thumbnail img-responsive"><img src="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-1-th.jpg" alt="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com"></a>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        Click per ingrandire
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-3 -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <div class="box-progetto">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Lorem.com</h4>
                    <a href="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-2.jpg" title="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com" class="fancybox thumbnail img-responsive"><img src="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-2-th.jpg" alt="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com"></a>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        Click per ingrandire
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-3 -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <div class="box-progetto">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Lorem.com</h4>
                    <a href="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-3.jpg" title="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com" class="fancybox thumbnail img-responsive"><img src="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-3-th.jpg" alt="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com"></a>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        Click per ingrandire
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-3 -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <div class="box-progetto">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Lorem.com</h4>
                    <a href="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-4.jpg" title="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com" class="fancybox thumbnail img-responsive"><img src="assets/img/fancybox/pretty-4-th.jpg" alt="Il nuovo sito di Lorem.com"></a>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        Click per ingrandire
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-3 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </section><!-- /section ultimi lavori -->

    <!-- Notizie e aggiornamenti -->
    <section id="news">
        <header class="header-sezione">
            <h2>News e aggiornamenti</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div id="segnalazioni-carousel" class="carousel slide">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="panel-carousel">
                                <div class="panel-carousel-heading">
                                    <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-carousel-body">
                                    <p>
                                        Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-carousel-footer">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#">Leggi tutta la news</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="panel-carousel">
                                <div class="panel-carousel-heading">
                                    <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-carousel-body">
                                    <p>
                                        Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-carousel-footer">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#">Leggi tutta la news</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="panel-carousel">
                                <div class="panel-carousel-heading">
                                    <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-carousel-body">
                                    <p>
                                        Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-carousel-footer">
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#">Leggi tutta la news</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-carousel-nav">
                        <p class="text-right">
                            <a class="panel-carousel-control" href="#segnalazioni-carousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a>
                            <a class="panel-carousel-control" href="#segnalazioni-carousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-5 -->
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div id="segnalazioni-tab">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Lorem ipsum</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Sit dolor</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">Adipiscing nunc</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Condimentum diam</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-1">
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">
                            <p>
                                Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at <a href="#">eget metus id elit mi</a> egetine. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus etiam sem...
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus, <a href="#">tellus ac cursus</a> comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3">
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc. Pellentesque fermentum, ante ac interdum ullamcorper.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Vivamus imperdiet condimentum diam, eget placerat felis consectetur id. Donec eget orci metus, ac adipiscing nunc.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-4">
                            <p>
                                Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at <a href="#">eget metus id elit mi</a> egetine. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus etiam sem...
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus, <a href="#">tellus ac cursus</a> comodo egetine metuss gorp.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col-sm-7 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
        <!-- Tabelle prezzi -->
        <section id="servizi">
            <header class="header-sezione">
                <h2>Servizi e offerte</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="list-group servizi">
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-titolo">
                            <h4>Opzione Free</h4>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-prezzo">
                            <strong>Gratuito</strong>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Dapibus ac facilisis in
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Morbi leo risus
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Porta ac consectetur ac
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Vestibulum at eros
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-round-bottom" type="button">
                                Abbonati
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="list-group servizi">
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-titolo">
                            <h4>Opzione Pro</h4>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-prezzo">
                            <strong>&euro; 5.99 al mese</strong>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Dapibus ac facilisis in
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Morbi leo risus
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Porta ac consectetur ac
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Vestibulum at eros
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-round-bottom" type="button">
                                Abbonati
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="list-group servizi">
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-titolo">
                            <h4>Opzione Super</h4>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-prezzo">
                            <strong>&euro; 9.99 al mese</strong>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Dapibus ac facilisis in
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Morbi leo risus
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Porta ac consectetur ac
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-opzione">
                            Vestibulum at eros
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item servizi-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-round-bottom" type="button">
                                Abbonati
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</div><!-- /.container -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In the previous code this is the section that show my posts into the homepage:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
        // Previous/next post navigation.
        twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

    else :
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
?>
```

But, as you can see, all the static contents that are situated under this PHP code is not shown (if I delete this part of code it work well and I can see the last part of my theme)

Do you have some idea about how can I solve this problem? What am I missing?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but does your theme have a `twentyfourteen_paging_nav` function?

I bet it does not. And that's the problem.

[So turn on debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

**// EDIT:**
There are also some HTML errors in your rendered page.
Duplicate `<html>` tag, incorrect parameter in `<nav class="navbar navbar-default"" role="navigation">` (note the double `"`), ...

Comment: mmm what is it  twentyfourteen_paging_nav ?

Comment: That is a custom function for pagination that comes with the _Twenty Fourteen_ WordPress core theme.

Comment: This is not Twenty Fourteen theme, why have I to use it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't, and that's the point exactly. Either set up your own pagination function or just hard-code the pagination (in a designated template file, for instance).